# Weighted synonyms

Tags: lucene, synonym

I use synonyms in lucene to increase the recall in the search. For that I construct a SynonymMap und use a SynonymGraphFilter in my custom Analyzer.
The synonym map looks like:

vw -> volkswagen

bmw -> bayerische motoren werke

I use QueryParser to parse the query.

Now I would like to lower the boost for synonym terms (e.g if I search for 'bmw', then the terms 'bayerische motoren werke' should have a lower boost)

How can I achieve it? It seems that Lucene supports this (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-9171) however I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches for handling synonyms, here:

(1) Your usage of [`SynonymMap`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/analyzers-common/index.html), which, as you note, is a way to pre-build synonym lists, which can then be used in analyzers and general queries.

(2) The enhancement you mention.

As the enhancement ticket notes,*"this has been done targeting the Synonyms Query."*.

The `SynonymQuery` class has a builder which allows you to add terms (as synonyms) with a [boost value](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SynonymQuery.Builder.html#addTerm-org.apache.lucene.index.Term-float-).

I do not believe there is any direct way to combine the two approaches. Synonym maps are not boost-aware. I think the best you can do is to iterate over your pre-defined list of synonyms, and feed the values into the synonym query builder.